# Update record by conditions Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

Can we update a record by conditions without check the record first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the method is update_all.

```
# Update all books with 'Rails' in their title
Book.update_all "author = 'David'", "title LIKE '%Rails%'"
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: Yes @Heikki is right, but beware that while you use **update_all**, it bypasses all validations defined in model. In short, it just generate an SQL query and executes it. It bypasses entire model and doesn't go through active record